# Can't launch Flutter - flutter run - Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, gradle, dart

Hey i can't execute the command `flutter run`, it output an error

```sh
Mattaio@DESKTOP-1TK6TKC MSYS .../Testing/myapp
$ flutter run --verbose
[  +14 ms] executing: [E:\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +73 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] b041144f833e05cf463b8887fa12efdec9493488
[        ] executing: [E:\flutter/] git tag --contains HEAD
[ +193 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --contains HEAD
[   +1 ms] 1.17.3
[   +6 ms] executing: [E:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +51 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [E:\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +45 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +88 ms] executing: [E:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +48 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +26 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +13 ms] executing: E:\Program Files\Android\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +28 ms] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:sdk_gphone_x86 device:generic_x86_arm transport_id:2
[   +4 ms] E:\Program Files\Android\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +33 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +135 ms] Generating D:\WorkFolder\Devlopment\Tests\Flutter\Testing\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +23 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +19 ms] Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
           "--enable-software-rendering".
[  +13 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
[   +6 ms] E:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe E:\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
E:\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names
-Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true --output-dill C:\Users\Mattaio\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tool.20452a49-aa3d-11ea-a88d-e0d55eb4b3b4\app.dill
--packages D:\WorkFolder\Devlopment\Tests\Flutter\Testing\myapp\.packages -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions
--enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root
[  +12 ms] executing: E:\Program Files\Android\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +28 ms] Exit code 0 from: E:\Program Files\Android\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of main
           06-09 12:36:47.950 D/WifiNative(  554): Scan result ready event
[  +10 ms] <- compile package:myapp/main.dart
[   +6 ms] executing: E:\Program Files\Android\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[  +20 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 30.0.1-6435776
           Installed as E:\Program Files\Android\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +2 ms] executing: E:\Program Files\Android\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +25 ms] Building APK
[  +13 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +1 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +3 ms] Using gradle from D:\WorkFolder\Devlopment\Tests\Flutter\Testing\myapp\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +1 ms] D:\WorkFolder\Devlopment\Tests\Flutter\Testing\myapp\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[  +11 ms] executing: E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[  +69 ms] Exit code 0 from: E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b06, mixed mode)
[   +4 ms] executing: [D:\WorkFolder\Devlopment\Tests\Flutter\Testing\myapp\android/]
D:\WorkFolder\Devlopment\Tests\Flutter\Testing\myapp\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-x86
-Ptarget=D:\WorkFolder\Devlopment\Tests\Flutter\Testing\myapp\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root
assembleDebug
[  +33 ms] Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.
[+3593 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
[        ] [  +13 ms] executing: [E:\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] [  +77 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] [        ] b041144f833e05cf463b8887fa12efdec9493488
[        ] [        ] executing: [E:\flutter/] git tag --contains HEAD
[        ] [ +200 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --contains HEAD
[        ] [        ] 1.17.3
[        ] [   +6 ms] executing: [E:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] [  +52 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] [        ] origin/stable
[        ] [        ] executing: [E:\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] [  +46 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] [  +91 ms] executing: [E:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] [  +48 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] [        ] stable
[        ] [  +20 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Le chemin d'acc�s sp�cifi� est introuvable.
[        ] Le chemin d'acc�s sp�cifi� est introuvable.
[        ] Le chemin d'acc�s sp�cifi� est introuvable.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [  +10 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [  +43 ms] Initializing file store
[        ] [  +11 ms] Done initializing file store
[ +259 ms] [+1114 ms] Skipping target: kernel_snapshot
[ +100 ms] [ +116 ms] debug_android_application: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.outputMissing}
[  +99 ms] [ +115 ms] debug_android_application: Complete
[        ] [  +15 ms] Persisting file store
[        ] [  +13 ms] Done persisting file store
[        ] [   +2 ms] build succeeded.
[        ] [  +14 ms] "flutter assemble" took 1 535ms.
[  +84 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * Where:
[        ] Script 'E:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[        ] > Process 'command 'E:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 4s
[        ] 1 actionable task: 1 executed
[ +337 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 4,6s)
[   +4 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +1 ms] "flutter run" took 5 149ms.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
#1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:569:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:723:18)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
#11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
#19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
#20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
#21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
#25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#27     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:556:7)
#28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
#29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
#31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
#32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

What can i do to fix this, any idea ?

Comment: try removing android.enableR8=true in gradle.properties file.

Comment: @SanketVekariya Thanks for your reply, i tried to remove android.enableR8=true but it don't works

Comment: check if flutter sdk is enabled?

Comment: @SanketVekariya Flutter doctor not displaying any error

Comment: remove settings.gradle file and run command flutter create . after that run command flutter run. Surely this will help you. :)